# Cpp code equation returning the same value regardless of input

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a wind chill calculator that works with temp. and wind speed values from user input. I have never used the pow() function before and I'm not sure if I am using it properly. My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float windChillCalculator(float T, float V)
{

    float wind_chill;
    wind_chill = (35.74 + (0.6215 * T) - (35.75 * (pow(V, 0.16)))
            + ((0.4275 * T) * (pow(V, 0.16))));
    return wind_chill;

}

int main()
{
    float T;
    float V;

    cout << "Enter temperature (F): " << endl;
    cin >> T;
    cout << "Enter wind speed (mph): " << endl;
    cin >> V;
    float wind_chill;
    windChillCalculator(T, V);
    cout << endl << "Wind chill is " << wind_chill << endl;

}
```

Regardless of input it returns 4.59e-41. Please help me figure out why..

Thanks.

Comment: Replace the `;` on the end of `float wind_chill;` in `main()` with `=`. It will be obvious why once you do it.

Comment: `wind_chill` is used without being initialized!

Comment: Your `main` function should return a value, like 0.

Comment: Simply: `float wind_chill = windChillCalculator (T, V);` in Main.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `wind_chill` in `windChillCalculator()` is a completely different variable than the one in `main()`.   Yes, they have the same name, but are in different scopes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - that is not required in C++.  Falling of the end of `main()` is specified as being the same as `return 0`.  That is not true for other functions - `main()` is special in that regard.

Comment: @Peter:  Yes, I know that it is not required in `main`.  The OP should be in the habit of returning values from functions that have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably that you are using two variables, both named `wind_chill`. First definition of `wind_chill` is in `windChillCalculator` function. This is local variable to function. Code outside of the function cannot see this variable (out of scope). Then `windChill` is defined out of the function, but is never asigned to.

Change line `windChillCalculator (T, V);` to `windChill = windChillCalculator (T, V);`

Answer (score 0):

you should put in main :
float wind_chill = windChillCalculator(T, V);